# Ubuntu 14.04 Canon iR-ADV C5030 Printing Issues

Tags: 14.04, drivers, printing, canon

I have a Canon iR-ADV C5030 printer, I have had troubles before with Linux, but now I have a new problem.

Canon developed the Linux drivers for this printer and they work great with the past versions of Ubuntu. Now everytime I try to print in version 14.04 I get "Filter failed"

```
 E [09/Aug/2014:12:32:10 -0400] [Job 32] Job stopped due to filter errors; 
please consult the error_log file for details.
```

[This is the full debug for a print attempt.](http://pastebin.com/T680dmrP)

Answer (score 3):

The new driver for the printer (CQue 2.0.7 Linux Driver) is working without any trouble.

[Download Printer Drivers](http://software.canon-europe.com/products/0010762.asp)

Just download it, install it and add the printer the same way you always do.

This only works if you did not install the older versions, does not matter that you uninstall it. I still don't know why, deleting the ppd from the systems does not do the trick, only a clean install of the printer works.